# osx ipv6 default routing

Tags: routing, mac-osx, ipv6

I've got an imac that's been running static ipv6 for years; I'm working on deploying ipv6 out to customers, and have the lan side of a test router plugged into a usb ethernet interface on the imac, which is properly getting a delegated address from the test router and it's getting a link-local default route from it:

```
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=4<VLAN_MTU>
    ether d0:37:45:b8:f3:64 
    inet 192.168.1.10 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::1427:aee3:e9e5:138%en5 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xf 
    inet6 2607:f678:2fff::843:5ec6:8b74:9785 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 

netstat -rn:
...
Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
default                                 2607:f678:1::1                  UGSc            en0
default                                 fe80::%utun0                    UGcI          utun0       
default                                 fe80::4a77:46ff:fef9:5bb3%en5   UGcI            en5       
...
```

When I delete the real default route (en0), ipv6 accesses get "no route to host" immediately (i.e. not from upstream, but the very first hop):

```
# traceroute6 google.com
connect: No route to host
```

The gateway is pingable:

```
# ping6 fe80::4a77:46ff:fef9:5bb3%en5 
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) fe80::1427:aee3:e9e5:138%en5 --> fe80::4a77:46ff:fef9:5bb3%en5
16 bytes from fe80::4a77:46ff:fef9:5bb3%en5, icmp_seq=0 hlim=64 time=0.708 ms
16 bytes from fe80::4a77:46ff:fef9:5bb3%en5, icmp_seq=1 hlim=64 time=0.638 ms
^C
```

I try deleting the utun0 route in case it's trying to use that, but get:

```
# route delete -inet6 default fe80::%utun0
route: writing to routing socket: not in table
delete net default: gateway fe80::%utun0: not in table
```

I'm not sure what's missing here...

Comment: I think part of your post is missing. What is this about a real default route on en0? What is the behavior you are expecting?

Comment: en0 is the real default route on our internal network; by deleting it, default should shift to en5 and go out through the test "customer" router, rather than our internal network.

Comment: Well, `fe80::` is not going to be an address on an interface without another address on the interface. Remember that the all-zeros address is the reserved router anycast address, and you need to create the address on an interface as an anycast address. Also, `en0` is s default route with a global address, but the RAs that define the default route must use a link-local address, and any default route should be a link-local address. You seem to be using OSX to try to shoehorn IPv6 into the way IPv4 works, rather than going with the way IPv6 is supposed to work.

Comment: That may be true, but it's clear the link local address isn't working...